# Why is the object 'values' not found in R?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have tried again and again but I don't know why the errors still there, this is the code I tried :

```
library(shiny)
library(neuralnet)
require(ggplot2)

# global
traininginput <-  as.data.frame(runif(50, min=0, max=100))
trainingoutput <- sqrt(traininginput)
trainingdata <- cbind(traininginput,trainingoutput)
colnames(trainingdata) <- c("Input","Output")
testdata <- as.data.frame((1:13)^2) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 12, class = "well",
           h4("Neural Network Plot"),

           plotOutput("main_plot"),

           hr(),

           numericInput(inputId = "HL1_noN",
                        label = "Hidden Layer 1 : Number of Neuron:",
                        value = 5),

           numericInput(inputId = "HL2_noN",
                        label = "Hidden Layer 2 : Number of Neuron:",
                        value = 5), 

           numericInput(inputId = "TL",
                        label = "Treshold level:",
                        value = 0.01,
                        step  = 0.01),

           actionButton("update", "Update View"),

           br(),
           br(),

           numericInput(inputId = "rmse_",
                         label = "Root Mean Square Error",
                         value = sqrt(sum((sqrt(testdata)- net.results)^2)/length(net.results))))))
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues(

    net.sqrt <- neuralnet(Output~Input,trainingdata, hidden=c(values$HL1_noN, values$HL2_noN), threshold=values$TL),
    net.results <- predict(net.sqrt, testdata), 
    cleanoutput <- cbind(testdata,sqrt(testdata),
                         as.data.frame(net.results)),
    colnames(cleanoutput) <- c("Input","ExpectedOutput","NeuralNetOutput"),

    rmse_ = sqrt(sum((sqrt(testdata)- net.results)^2)/length(net.results)),

    HL1_noN = 5,
    HL2_noN = 5,
    TL      = 0.007,
    rmse_   = sqrt(sum((sqrt(testdata)- net.results)^2)/length(net.results)))

  observeEvent(input$update, {
    net.sqrt <- neuralnet(Output~Input,trainingdata, hidden=c(values$HL1_noN, values$HL2_noN), threshold=values$TL)
    net.results <- predict(net.sqrt, testdata) 
    cleanoutput <- cbind(testdata,sqrt(testdata),
                         as.data.frame(net.results))
    colnames(cleanoutput) <- c("Input","ExpectedOutput","NeuralNetOutput")

    values$HL1_noN <- input$HL1_noN
    values$HL2_noN <- input$HL2_noN
    values$TL      <- input$TL
    values$rmse_   <- input$rmse_ })

  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({
    net.sqrt <- neuralnet(Output~Input,trainingdata, hidden=c(values$HL1_noN, values$HL2_noN), threshold=values$TL)
    net.results <- predict(net.sqrt, testdata)
    cleanoutput <- cbind(testdata,sqrt(testdata),
                         as.data.frame(net.results))
    colnames(cleanoutput) <- c("Input","ExpectedOutput","NeuralNetOutput")
    ggplot(data = cleanoutput, aes(x= ExpectedOutput, y= NeuralNetOutput)) + geom_point() +
      geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1
                  , color="brown", size=0.5)})}

shinyApp(ui,server)

# rmse_ = sqrt(sum((sqrt(testdata)- net.results)^2)/length(net.results))
```

I think my mistake is I plug the formula straight into the `'values'`. But I really hope it can calculate the value of `rmse_` when I assign the value of `Hidden Layer 1`, `Hidden Layer 2`, and `Threshold Level`. Which part should I change? Can anyone give me some hints? Or I have used the wrong function already?

I am sorry if the way I ask is a little bit inappropriate. Because I am new to `R`, can anyone give me some tips about how to do it? I tried my best, and I am not sure whether I am on the right path or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried simplifying what you have:

- I assumed you wanted to update the numericInput `rmse_` after the calculations; so you could have a placeholder in your `ui` for value that will get updated after the actionbutton `update` is pressed
- You can have an `eventReactive` expression that will be called when `update` button pressed. Here you can run your neural net. The number hidden layers will come from your inputs.
- The `updateNumericInput` will update the `rmse_` value when recalculated.
- Your render plot will call the reactive expression to get updated data and automatically replot after `update` pressed.
- If you don't want someone to edit your `rmse_` in the `ui` you might want to utilize `textOutput` instead of `numericInput` - would be relatively easy to modify further.

Let me know if this is closer to what you need.

```
library(shiny)
library(neuralnet)
require(ggplot2)

# global
traininginput <-  as.data.frame(runif(50, min=0, max=100))
trainingoutput <- sqrt(traininginput)
trainingdata <- cbind(traininginput,trainingoutput)
colnames(trainingdata) <- c("Input","Output")
testdata <- as.data.frame((1:13)^2) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 12, class = "well",
           h4("Neural Network Plot"),

           plotOutput("main_plot"),

           hr(),

           numericInput(inputId = "HL1_noN",
                        label = "Hidden Layer 1 : Number of Neuron:",
                        value = 5),

           numericInput(inputId = "HL2_noN",
                        label = "Hidden Layer 2 : Number of Neuron:",
                        value = 5), 

           numericInput(inputId = "TL",
                        label = "Threshold level:",
                        value = 0.01,
                        step  = 0.01),

           actionButton("update", "Update View"),

           br(),
           br(),

           numericInput(inputId = "rmse_",
                        label = "Root Mean Square Error",
                        value = NULL
                        ))))
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  cleanoutput <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    net.sqrt <- neuralnet(Output~Input,trainingdata, hidden=c(input$HL1_noN, input$HL2_noN), threshold=input$TL)
    net.results <- predict(net.sqrt, testdata) 
    cleanoutput <- cbind(testdata,sqrt(testdata), as.data.frame(net.results))
    colnames(cleanoutput) <- c("Input","ExpectedOutput","NeuralNetOutput")
    updateNumericInput(session, inputId = "rmse_", value = sqrt(sum((sqrt(testdata)- net.results)^2)/length(net.results)))
    return(cleanoutput)
  })

  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = cleanoutput(), aes(x= ExpectedOutput, y= NeuralNetOutput)) + 
      geom_point() +
      geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color="brown", size=0.5)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

If you want to have `rmse` as text output (instead of an input), change `ui` from `numericInput` to `textOutput("rmse")` and server could include:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv_rmse <- reactiveVal()

  cleanoutput <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    net.sqrt <- neuralnet(Output~Input,trainingdata, hidden=c(input$HL1_noN, input$HL2_noN), threshold=input$TL)
    net.results <- predict(net.sqrt, testdata) 
    cleanoutput <- cbind(testdata,sqrt(testdata), as.data.frame(net.results))
    colnames(cleanoutput) <- c("Input","ExpectedOutput","NeuralNetOutput")
    rv_rmse(sqrt(sum((sqrt(testdata)- net.results)^2)/length(net.results)))
    return(cleanoutput)
  })

  output$rmse <- renderText(paste("Root Mean Square Error:", rv_rmse()))

  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = cleanoutput(), aes(x= ExpectedOutput, y= NeuralNetOutput)) + 
      geom_point() +
      geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color="brown", size=0.5)
  })

}
```

Comment: yes yes, your assumption was correct, those are what I mean. Oh, now I know that the value should be NULL instead of the formula ... and I learnt a new function updateNumericInput and a lot from you. Thank you very much Ben, I will revise the code you updated to me. Really very helpful, have a nice day yeah !!!